# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist in github action ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, github-actions

Trying to run my automation script in Github actions and encountering `UnknownError` issue. The same script is working in my machine.

````
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is 
   no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)```
````

This is my Github action workflow chrome driver part

```
  - name: Set up Chrome
    uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@latest
    with:
      chrome-version: stable

  - name: Download chrome driver
    uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@master

  - name: Launch chrome driver
    run: |
      export DISPLAY=:99
      chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub &
      sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 & # optional
```

I have tried lot of solutions from different answers in Stackoverflow. None of them worked for me, Appreciate your help!

Comment: how are you running your script? 
Mine is -
        run: |
          google-chrome --version
          export DISPLAY=:99
          chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub &
          sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 & npm run local-selenium

also I use 

      - uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@v1.0.1

if that is any help